# Rails: Dynamic select menu

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

I'm following the tutorial of railscast #88 Dynamic select menus. I got an error in jquery part of it. I'm not a familiar in jquery I just follow his tutorial, I already searched the error.

Error on console log

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: $serviceprovider_service_id :selected
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@serviceprovider, html: { :multipart => true }, class: 'form-horizontal') do |f| %>

      <div class="form-group">
            <label class="client-login-label">Service</label>
            <%= f.collection_select(:service_id, Service.all, :id, :service, prompt: 'Choose Service') %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
            <label class="client-login-label">Category</label>
            <%= f.grouped_collection_select(:category_id, Service.order(:service), :categories, :service, :id, :name, prompt: 'Choose Category') %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.submit("Register", class: 'btn btn-lg btn-success client-signin-btn') %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

serviceprovider.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
    categories = $('#serviceprovider_category_id').html()
    $('#serviceprovider_service_id').change ->
        service = $('#serviceprovider_service_id :selected').text()
        options = $(categories).filter("optgroup[label='#{service}']").html()
        if options
            $('#serviceprovider_category_id').html(options)
        else
            $('#serviceprovider_category_id').empty()
```

What's wrong with this. even I created a custom js file not a coffeescript it had a the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Pepeng,

The first thing I've noticed is that collection_select and grouped_collection_select are not using the block parameter f.  Change them to f.collection_select and f.grouped_collection_select.

The second thing is that the code is selecting from the :serviceprovider column for both collection_select and grouped_collection_select when it probably needs to be selecting the :service_id and :category_id respectively.

Comment: Thank you sir, I already change the first thing you suggested.. but I didn't get the second thing sir(if it is okay sir can you give an example). I just follow the railscast #88 because I want to get the the same result, what the screencast made. Thank you!